# Spring app saving documents to test db instead of custom db

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, yaml

I have a spring restful web service and am trying to save to a database named little-data but my app keeps saving to the test database instead.

Below is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
    port: 27017
    uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1/little-data
    repositories:
      enabled: true
    authentication-database: admin


server:
  port: 8090
```

I have also tried this for my application yaml file:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 27017
    database: little-data
    repositories:
      enabled: true
    authentication-database: admin


server:
  port: 8090
```

And here is my model for posts:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import lombok.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "posts")

public class Post {

    @Id
    @Field("id")
    private int id;

    @Field("gameName")
    private String gameName;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    @Field("gameGenre")
    private String gameGenre;

    public Post(int id, String game, String genre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.gameName = game;
        this.gameGenre = genre;
    }
}
```

All of the requests work fine but they save to the wrong database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your YAML config, please notice that `host` and `port` are *children* of `mongodb` and not in the same level as you do (if it's not already a typo), like this:

```
spring:
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 27017
            database: little-data
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use profiles? A possible application.yaml could look like this:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: production
---
spring:
    profiles: development
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 27017
            database: test-db
---
spring:
    profiles: production
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 27017
            database: little-data
```

As [Laabidi Raissi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692580/laabidi-raissi) said, it be careful to get the indentation right.